# how to stop reading a fragment database

Tags: android

I have a question, please help. I have 6 snippets of "ПН", "ВТ" and so on. When I first open, there is only one table, when I switch to “ВТ” and return, there are already two. When I repeat again, there are already four of them, and each time it increases. Here is my code
DatabaseHelper

```
public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15){
        DB_PATH=context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    }else {
        DB_PATH= Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void checkAndCopyDatabase(){
    boolean dbExist= checkDatabase();
    if (dbExist){
        Log.d("TAG", "database already exist");
    }else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    try {
        copyDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG","Error copy dadabase");
    }
}
public boolean checkDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }catch (SQLException e){

    }
    if (checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public  void openDatabase(){
    String myPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public  synchronized void close(){
    if (myDatabase != null){
        myDatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
public Cursor QueryData(String query){
    return myDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
}
```

}

my №1 Fragments
tabItem

```
public class tabItem  extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
private Cursor cursor;
String classID;
private VocabularyAdapter adapter;
@NonNull
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,container,false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    return viewGroup;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    classID = bundle.getString("classID");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    try {
        databaseHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
        databaseHelper.openDatabase();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cursor = databaseHelper.QueryData("select * from tort" + " where par=1 and day=1");
        if (cursor != null){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.setPar(cursor.getString(3));
                    item.setKobinet(cursor.getString(4));
                    item.setSabak(cursor.getString(5));
                    item.setMugalim(cursor.getString(6));
                    item.setUakit(cursor.getString(7));
                    arrayList.add(item);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    adapter = new VocabularyAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
    adapter.setOnTapListener(new OnTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnTapView(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click to "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: For heads up, as per the class naming convention in java, Class name always start with the Capitalize character. (i.e instead of tabItem, it should be TabItem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your fragment's onResume() method calls every time. For quick fix please add below code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (arrayList != null && arrayList.isEmpty()) {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper (getActivity());
        try {
            databaseHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
            databaseHelper.openDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cursor = databaseHelper.QueryData("select * from tort" + " where par=1 and day=1");
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Item item = new Item();
                        item.setPar(cursor.getString(3));
                        item.setKobinet(cursor.getString(4));
                        item.setSabak(cursor.getString(5));
                        item.setMugalim(cursor.getString(6));
                        item.setUakit(cursor.getString(7));
                        arrayList.add(item);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        adapter = new VocabularyAdapter (getActivity(), arrayList);
        adapter.setOnTapListener(new OnTapListener () {
            @Override
            public void OnTapView(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click to " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (arrayList != null && arrayList.isEmpty()) {
         arrayList.clear()
   }
   //All your db operation code will go here..
}
```